# Send newsletter with view

Tags: views, emails

I'm trying to send a newsletter with a view.
I'm using the code
`<?php
  $viewName = 'my_view_name';
  print views_embed_view($viewName);
?>`
which works fine when I sent a test email. 
But when the newsletter is send for the users the email content is empty.

Any suggestions ?
Thanks a lot